# return empty result via using Entrez,Efetch to search lineage from taxonomy db

Tags: python, database, biopython, ncbi

I used biopython to search lineage information from taxonomy database, but it returns empty !

I can used it yesterday(2016/3/15) ! But now I can't used it(2016/03/16)!

The code I used is here,

```
>>> from Bio import Entrez   
>>> Entrez.email = "myemail@gmail.com"   
>>> handle = Entrez.esearch(db="Taxonomy", term="Cypripedioideae")    
>>> record = Entrez.read(handle)   
>>> record["IdList"]   
['158330']  
>>> record["IdList"][0]  
'158330'  
>>> handle = Entrez.efetch(db="Taxonomy", id="158330", retmode="xml")  
>>> records = Entrez.read(handle)   
>>> records[0].keys()  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> records
[]  #I can't understand why it returns empty today?
```

Comment: What did your output look like on 3.15.2016?

Comment: Entrez API fails a lot. That's it. I've encountered errors now, and the same code works a minute later.